# Average to collect baseball cards

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

A young baseball fan wants to collect a complete set of 262 baseball cards.
The baseball cards are available in a completely random fashion, one per package of chewing gum.

The fan buys two packets of chewing gum each day. How long on average will it take the
fan to get a complete set?

I understand that this is a coupon's collector's problem. So, the general formula for this is:

$$= (262)\ln_{262}$$

which gives me **1458.9** as an answer.

Now I divided this by two since he buys two packs a day. Thus, I get $729$ days.

What I am confused, is the $average$ part of the question. Does the average involve a different formula or calculation?

Comment: If you have understood the coupon's collector problem, $m\log m$ *is* the formula for the *average* number of days required to complete the collection.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I missed that. So the formula is for the average days, then since he buys two, 729 should be the final answer, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. $\phantom{}$

Comment: It is expected that he will need to buy 1459 cards before he has a full set.  If he buys two packs of cards, how many cards are in a pack?  not given.    The final answer should be 1459/(2 packs/day * n cards / pack).

Comment: there is one per pack. It is stated in the problem

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but the formula for the expectation should perhaps be half of that for the coupon collector's problem, so  $$\frac12 \cdot 262 \sum_{n=1}^{262} \frac1n$$ and if you work this out it is closer to $805.3$ than $729$

The approximation based on the harmonic series would be  something like $$\frac12 \cdot 262 \left( \log_e(262) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2\cdot262} + \ldots \right)$$ where $\gamma\approx 0.5772156649\ldots$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant, making a substantial difference to the result

Comment: so what does the formula $m\ln_m$ gives me then?

Comment: It gives you the value of $\displaystyle m \int_1^m \frac1x \, dx$ which is not quite the same as  $\displaystyle  m \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac1n$, as the multiplication by $m$ turns a small error into a larger one